# Delete all rows after first match of value in first row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to delete all rows after the first match of the value "##Section" in column A.

My spreadsheet looks like this :

```
blah
blah
blah
##Section
blep
blep
blep
##Section
Hi
hi
...
```

Here's my current code (not working) :

```
   Dim rng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    With Sheets("import")
        'find Terminations
        Set rng = .Range("A:A").Find(what:="##Section", after:=.Range("A1")).Row
        'if ##Section NOT found - exit from sub
        If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        'find last row
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            lastRow = .Cells.Find(what:="*", _
                          after:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            lastRow = 1
        End If
        'I use lastRow + 1 to prevent deletion "##Section" when it is on lastrow
        .Range(rng.Row + 1 & ":" & lastRow + 1).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End With
```

Comment: *"Here's my current code (not working)"*, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the line

```
Set rng = .Range("A:A").Find(what:="##Section", after:=.Range("A1")).Row
```

You are trying to store a `Long` Value in a `Range` variable

Try this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim sRow As Long, lastRow As Long

    With Sheets("import")
        'find Terminations
        Set rng = .Range("A:A").Find(what:="##Section", after:=.Range("A1"))

        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            '~~> Get the start row
            sRow = rng.Row + 1

            'find last row
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
                lastRow = .Cells.Find(what:="*", _
                    after:=.Range("A1"), _
                    Lookat:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Row
            Else
                lastRow = 1
            End If
            'I use lastRow + 1 to prevent deletion "##Section" when it is on lastrow
            .Range(sRow & ":" & lastRow + 1).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Or a succinct version

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim StartRow As Long, LastRow As Long

    Set ws = Sheets("import")

    With ws
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            '~~> Find last row
            LastRow = .Cells.Find(what:="*", _
                      after:=.Range("A1"), _
                      Lookat:=xlPart, _
                      LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                      MatchCase:=False).Row + 1 '<~~ Added + 1 to last row here

            '~~> Identify your range and find
            Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Find(what:="##Section", after:=.Range("A1"))

            If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                '~~> Get the start row
                StartRow = rng.Row + 1

                '~~> Delete the range
                .Range(StartRow & ":" & LastRow).Delete Shift:=xlUp
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That's it ! Thanks. Can it also delete the row matching "##Section" ?

Comment: Yup.. Change `StartRow = rng.Row + 1` to `StartRow = rng.Row` :)